# "Parameter name omitted" Error when migrate objc to swift , dealing with closure

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, migration

I'm migrating my object-c project to swift, I can use closure for block , but there is error "Parameter name omitted", I have to add the paramater by my self, instead of generated automatically by xcode

here is my swift closure code, the closure has parameters

```
 func GET(urlSting:String!,
    parameters:[String: AnyObject]?,
    success:((responseObject:AnyObject?) -> Void)?,
    failure:((error:NSError?) -> Void)?){
       // somethings
}
```

here is my code generated in `project-Swift.h`, block has no parameter

```
- (void)GET:(NSString * __null_unspecified)urlSting 
        parameters:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * __nullable)parameters 
        success:(void (^ __nullable)(id __nullable))success 
        failure:(void (^ __nullable)(NSError * __nullable))failure;
```

here is my code in objc.m, block has no parameter,

```
[[APIClientS sharedClient] GET:"www.google.com/xxxx" 
            parameters:nil
            success:^(id _Nullable) {

            } failure:^(NSError * _Nullable) {

            }];
```

I need to add the parameters by myself,

```
failure:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
```

It is really a boring work , how can I generate the parameter name automatically ??

---

Edit -2015-11-22 09:48:24

Answer Bobj-C's Question:
`what do you mean "block has no parameter" ?`

As the Following the Pic show, the block not have parameter `error`, I have to add it by myself

[image]

Comment: what do you mean "block has no parameter" ?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: haven't, just add parameter name manually

Comment: I'll have to add the completion block parameters manually as well.  I am using Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 3